# Tunneling a specific IP and port from server A to server B

Tags: linux, windows, firewall

This is our situation, we want traffic that comes in to our server A ip to be sent(tunneled) to a specific ip on server B, and accept replies coming back from server B to server A. How can this be done with iptables?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 2):

to ensure that traffic both ways passes the server A run apply on it following iptables rules:

```
# this will forward all the relevant traffic to the server b
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -d ip.address.of.a -j DNAT --to ip.address.of.b:1234
# and this will make sure there's no triangular routing - all packets forwarded to b 
# will have source  ip address of a, return communication will always go via a
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -d ip.address.of.b -j MASQUERADE
```

if just forwarding is not enough - i suggest you establish a vpn between a and b [using openvp, ipsec or just ssh port forwarding with a watchdog] and apply similar firewall rules.

Comment: +1 -- I forgot to SNAT / masquerade in my answer.

Comment: @JeffFerland - just DNAT can work - it all depends on other statefull devices between the initiator of the connection and server b.

Answer (score 0):

In linux you just install rinetd for your distro and configure the parameters, and you are done.

Windows has a port as well: http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-install-and-configure-port-forwarding-using-rinetd-in-windows/

Yes, iptables can do that as well but I have always used rinetd as it is more straightforward.